# How do I make the category sidebar widget (stock) display the total # of posts including those in subcategories?

Tags: categories, widgets, sidebar, hierarchical

Thanks for taking a look at this for me.

You can see the current behavior at http://dev.citylightphilly.com/blog/ -- Here is my specific problem.

We are using a category structure like this:

```
Events []
  Meals and Mission []
  Service []
```

Our problem is that our users are categorizing events like this:

```
Events []
  Meals and Mission [x]
  Service []
```

This results in the sidebar widget not reflecting the total number of events in the post count.  For instance - we have 8 posts in "Meals and Mission" and 2 that are simply in the "Events" category.  We'd like the sidebar to reflect the total post count like this

```
Events (10)
  Meals and Mission (8)
```

However, the post count looks like this:

```
Events (2)
  Meals and Mission (8)
```

**EDIT:**  moved the quick fix to an 'answer' below.

What I'd prefer to do is tweak the widget to reflect the total number of posts in that category, including all its child categories.  Is this possible?  I'm using the stock "categories" widget.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't THE answer, but it's one answer.

Quick fix:  Have my clients check two boxes whenever they use a sub-category. (sub-category box + parent category).  This will ensure the post-count is correct.

```
Events [x]
  Meals and Mission [x]
```

Would love a fix that didn't depend on clients checking both boxes all the time.